# Hiding Android Keyboard after Pressing Back Button

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am using this code to hide the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

This works well. However, I noticed a bug. If I have initially hidden the keyboard using my phone physical back button, then I called the above method, the keyboard will be shown instead of hidden. In other word, seem like the Android system failed to detect I have hidden the keyboard using back button. Instead of hiding the keyboard, it show the keyboard. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the piece of code, when you use hide keyboard functionality?

Comment: facing same problem please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change this line from

```
 imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

to

```
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

As using toggle change the state on the basis of current state. 
If its hidden it will show and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

```
//hide-keyboard:
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

//show-keyboard:
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are toggling the keyboard. Try this:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

or you can add in Androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".views.activities.tile_details.TileDetailActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/TileDetails.AppTheme.Light"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

or

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(View view, Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```